# Creating Streams from endpoints and NHD Stream Layer using ArcGIS Pro with Spatial Analyst

Tags: arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, excel, hydrology

I have a dataset for instream flow water rights that delineates the length of stream based on upstream and downstream endpoints and the miles of stream. I'm trying to create a GIS layer for this dataset and show the specific lengths of streams in the dataset. Obviously, if I just create a line layer with the upstream and downstream coordinates, the lines are straight.

Can I clip this layer to the NHD streams layer to show the streams specifically with meandering or is there something I'm missing or some way I can do this?

I'm using Excel and ArcGIS Pro. The data I have is just two sets of point coordinates (decimal degrees) for the endpoints. I'm using the Spatial Analyst extension to ArcGIS Pro too.

Comment: Kindly mention the software you are using.

Comment: And what kind of data are your instream water rights?  Point, lines, polygons, tabular?

Comment: Are you using the Spatial Analyst extension to ArcGIS Pro, ArcMap or something else?

Comment: The term of art for matching coarse features to more detailed ones is "conflation". It might be somewhat labor intensive (depending on the quality of the endpoint data).